# Bizarre resizing within custom fullscreen NSWindow?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, subclass, nsview, nswindow

I have a custom-subclassed NSWindow which is made into a fullscreen borderless window with NSBordelessWindowMask. It works perfectly, and as far as I can see, there are no problems or anything strange about the window itself.

What I am trying to figure out why exactly a custom-subclassed NSView within the aforementioned window is respoding to setFrame: requests in an odd manner.  Rather than simply taking the requests as they are, it seems they are going through some sort of change - for example, setting the x coordinate to 25 and the width to 800 does not put the right edge of the view at 825 as one would expect. Instead, the width/height grow along with the x and y coordinates, even though they report the proper numbers when asked by [view frame].size.width with an NSLog.

The sizing masks should not be an issue, as I have disabled them entirely and get the same result with several different configurations.

Has anybody else experienced this type of behavior?

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see how you are creating the window and view?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code that you're using to create the window/view it's hard to know what might be causing this. That said, if you're targeting Leopard of later, there's a built in way to make a view go fullscreen which might help. The method is `enterFullScreenMode:withOptions:` on NSView. If you want the entire window to go fullscreen you can call this on the `contentView` of the the window. This may not fix your bug, but it should simplify things a bit at least.